# How to determine whether the extremum of a functional is a minimum, maximum, or saddle point

Tags: functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, calculus-of-variations

Consider the following functional:
$$
F[y] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(y,\dot{y}, x) dx
$$
The variation can be expanded to second order as following, where we also assume that variations vanish $\delta y$ vanish at the boundaries and that the path $x$ is an extremum and annihilates the first order terms. We use integration by parts to go from the second line to the third line:
\begin{align*}
\delta F &= \int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(y+\delta y,\dot{y} + \delta{\dot{y}}, x) dx - \int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(y,\dot{y}, x) dx \newline
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\bigg[ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \delta y \delta y + 2 \frac{\delta^2 f}{\partial y \partial \dot{y}}\delta y\delta \dot{y} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \dot{y}^2} \delta{\dot{y}}\delta{\dot{y}}\bigg]\newline
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\bigg[ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \delta y \delta y - \frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial \dot{y}}\bigg) \delta y \delta y + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \dot{y}^2} \delta{\dot{y}}\delta{\dot{y}}\bigg]
\end{align*}

Are there any theorems (in particular, iff statements) that explain any conditions on the derivatives that make the integral positive, negative, or zero?

Comment: You're mixing notations here so it is hard to verify any of your work. You can't have $y(x)$ and $x(t)$ at the same time.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for pointing that out. $\dot{y}$ refers to $\frac{dy}{dx}$